# Does Node.JS App with Thousands Concurrent Users Need Connection Pooling

Tags: node.js, connection-pooling

Does a node.js app with thousands of concurrent users really need to use connection pooling mechanism ?

***EDITED:***
App could be an ecommerce app that requires high volume for reading and writing to databases.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. It depends in what situation. You should be able to handle thousands of concurrent connections but of course it all depends on what you do in those connection handlers. This is the only answer that can really be given with so little details in the question.

Comment: what if the app is an ecommerce app that requires high volumes for reading and writing to database ? If it needs connection pooling, how to determine the optimal maximum pooling size ?